# Using `wicked_pdf` in a non-rails project

Tags: ruby

All the documentation for `wicked_pdf` assume you are using `rails`.

But I want to use this feature in a non-rails environment (a Jekyll plugin, written in Ruby).

Trying to use `pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(page.content)` returns `Error:  uninitialized constant WickedPdf`.

How do I initialize `WickedPdf` without the `rails generate wicked_pdf` provided in their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `gem 'activesupport'` to my gemfile, then use `require 'wicked_pdf'` in my source code.

Answer (score 1):

[wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) depends on `active_support/core_ext` - as you can see in [lib/wicked_pdf.rb](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L14-L24). However you can use it outside of controller "context" like this...

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>My life is wicked.</h1>')
```